# Spring Security form login

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Spring Boot application with custom login page under src/main/webapp/my-login.html. I configured Spring Security as below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/my-login").permitAll().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

How can I make HTTP GET to /my-login return my HTML page? I am aware that it's named "my-login.html" instead of simply "my-login", but removing .html extension makes Chrome go crazy (it tries to download the file...). I tried putting the HTML file (with or without extension) under src/main/webapp or src/main/resources/static.

Also please note I'm not using Thymeleaf, target frontend framework will be AngularJS. I'm also interested in elegant solution (I think what I want to achieve is quite simple goal) - I think I made it work with loginPage("/my-login.html") but the REST endpoints just don't seem right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a view controller to forward the request to my-login.html...

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/my-login").setViewName("forward:/my-login.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm not sure if that's the cleanest solution, but I quite like it + it directly responded my question = I marked it as a working solution for me :)

Comment: @httPants I am also facing the same issue. when I enter the correct username and password file automatically getting downloaded and adding /forward it goes to an infinite condition where a request is forwarded to /login. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use AngularJS for frontend application, then creating an API authentication endpoint is probably the best solution. You can use any authentication mechanism you wish, but simple basic auth (optionally with some persistent tokens) is fine for start. So, you would have a special endpoint, e.g:

`/token POST` that is protected by basic auth and on success would return a token object, which can be later used for all requests (for example in request headers).

Your AngularJS would be a totally separate application, which only consumes your API endpoints. This app can optionally keep the authentication token in client session, so the user don't have to enter credentials each time app is opened. Plus, this is a very clean solution, which can be easily tested in isolation. Also, this way the frontend app can be developed by other team, without any knowledge about Spring technical details.

Answer (score 1):

I played a little more with formLogin properties and got to this solution:

```java
formLogin().loginPage("/my-login.html").loginProcessingUrl("/my-login").defaultSuccessUrl("/my-home.html", true).permitAll()
```

This way I have HTML file returned as login page and a clean POST endpoint for passing login data.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. when I enter the correct username and password file automatically getting downloaded I have also tried out your solution and adding /forward it goes to an infinite condition where a request is forwarded to /login. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @PatelRomil it was 2 years ago so I might not remember correctly, but I think my solution was without request forwarding.